# Update Only changed Objects inside Array inside ngFor?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a JSON(Array of Objects) coming from server for each second.I would like to update UI only for the objects whose data changes and unchanged object remain as same before.I am supposing data arrived 2 times from server.

```
1st time:

[
  {} //Object1
  {} //Object2
  {} //Object3
]

2nd time:

 [
  {} //Object1.Changed
  {} //Object2.Unchanged
  {} //Object3.changed
 ]
```

I want to display all 3 objects in UI but I want changes to be reflected to only Object1 and Object3 and I do not want to **TOUCH** Object2 as it is not changed.

Is it Possible ?

Comment: yes, it is possible [need to think] but why do you want this? Any special reason?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this expensive operation, you can customize the default tracking algorithm. by supplying the **trackBy** option to **NgForOf**. trackBy takes a function that has two arguments: index and item. If trackBy is given, Angular tracks changes by the return value of the function.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of collection;trackBy: trackByFn">{{item.id}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button (click)="getItems()">Refresh items</button>
  `,
})
export class App {

  constructor() {
    this.collection = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
  }

  getItems() {
    this.collection = this.getItemsFromServer();
  }

  getItemsFromServer() {
    return [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];
  }

  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index; // or item.id
  }
}
```